# Fourier transform of a random subset of $Z_n$

Tags: probability, fourier-transform, additive-combinatorics

I have been watching [a lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QdWNydi7f4s) about introduction to additive combinatorics. Starting from minute 16:00 or so, the speaker makes a claim which I do not understand. I included all the details here.

Given a function $f : \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, it's Fourier transform at a point $r \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is defined by
$$\hat{f}(r) = \mathbb{E}_{x \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}} f(x) e^{2\pi i x/n} .$$

The claim is that if $A \subseteq \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is chosen at random, by picking every element of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ to be in $A$ with probability $0.5$ and independently of other choices, then $\hat{1}_A(1) \approx 1/\sqrt{n}$. That is, the Fourier transform of the indicator function of $A$ at $1$ should be roughly $1/\sqrt{n}$. The way that I understand it is that the expectation of $\hat{1}_A(1)$ is roughly $1/\sqrt{n}$.

I don't understand why it shouldn’t be $0$. Here is my argument:

For every $a \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ define the random variable $X_a = e^{2 \pi i a/n}$ if $a \in A$, and $X_a = 0$ otherwise. Then $\mathbb{E}[X_a] = \frac{1}{2}e^{2 \pi i a/n}$.
Then,

$$\hat{1}_A(1) = \frac{1}{n} \sum _{a \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}} X_a$$
and

$$\mathbb{E}[\hat{1}_A(1)] = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{a \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{E}[X_a] = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{a \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}} e^{2 \pi i a/n} = 0$$

since the last step is just the sum of roots of unity.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of the Fourier transform is suspect. It should be something like
$$\hat{f}(r) = E_{x \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}}f(x)\exp(2\pi i r x / n) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{x = 0}^{n - 1}f(x)\exp(2\pi i r x / n).$$
I'll write
$$\hat{1_A}(j) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j = 0}^{n - 1}1_A(k)w_n^{jk},$$
where
$$w_n = \exp(2\pi i / n).$$
Then
$$E(\hat{1_A}(j)) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j = 0}^{n - 1}\frac{1}{2}w_n^{jk} = \frac{1}{2}I(j = 0).$$
And
\begin{align}
\text{Cov}(\hat{1_A}(j), \hat{1_A}(k)) &= \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{\ell = 0}^{n - 1}w_n^{(j - k)\ell}\text{Cov}(1_A(\ell), 1_A(\ell)) \\
&= \frac{1}{4n^2}\sum_{\ell = 0}^{n - 1}w_n^{(j - k)\ell} \\
&= \frac{1}{4n}I(j = k).
\end{align}
Hence $E(\hat{1_A}) = \frac{1}{2}e_0$ and the covariance matrix is $\frac{1}{4n}I$. So $\hat{1_A}(1)$ is mean $0$ with variance $\frac{1}{4n}$.